# SQL adding value at every comma separation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some query to sys.Columns that giving result :

```
DECLARE @queryRWordsSameType VARCHAR(500) ='[ItemCode],[ItemDesc],[ItemId],[ItemName]'
```

How do i do to make the value for each comma separated be like  :

```
DECLARE @queryRWordsSameType VARCHAR(500) ='CAST([ItemCode] AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS [ItemCode]
    ,CAST([ItemDesc] AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS [ItemDesc]
    ,CAST([ItemId] AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS [ItemId]
    ,CAST([ItemName] AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS [ItemName]'
```

Comment: Could you please add your query on sys.Columns? I don't understand quite what you need to do, sorry. Can you explain a little more clearly?

Comment: Do you want to insert (add) value to that column **or** select (extract) value from that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go (though this is building the whole string directly from syscolumns):

```
DECLARE @queryRWordsSameType VARCHAR(500) = ''
SELECT @queryRWordsSameType += CASE WHEN @queryRWordsSameType <> '' THEN ',' ELSE '' END + 'CAST([' + name + '] AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS [' + name + ']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
  FROM syscolumns
 WHERE id = object_id('YOUR_TABLE_NAME')
PRINT @queryRWordsSameType
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're selecting all columns of an sql table as comma delimited list, correct?

We can use the COALESCE function for the comma seperated value. As for the columns, see sys.columns and sys.tables definition.

You may use this snippet.

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',', '') + '[' + c.name + ']'
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = '<Your Table>'

SELECT @listStr
```